# How do you update SVN?

Tags: svn, versioning

I found this website but does not seem to work. 
http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/updating-svn-mac-os-x/

when I execute this:

```
bash-3.2$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-neon
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

I get an error.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to build `svn` from sources.  Do you have the sources?

Comment: @StevenDobbelaere: Did the other commands listed before the `--with-neon` work fine?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#osx and download the version you need for OS X and install it. This will install the new svn into /opt/subversion/bin
2. Got to your terminal and check your $PATH by typing "echo $PATH". If you don't see /opt/subversion/bin in there, make sure you add it by typing export PATH=/opt/subversion/bin:$PATH. If it DOES exist and appears AFTER /usr/bin, then you may need to remove an older copy of svn that came installed on OS X. To do so, go to /usr/bin and remove all files starting with svn. This isn't an exact science but it should do the trick.
3. Make sure you reload your .profile first by typing
   . ./.profile*
   Type "svn --version". You should see that you have the newest version installed!